# Filebeat not reading logs from nested directories

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk

I am relatively new to ELK stack and I am trying to send logs from a linux servers to elasticsearch. The path I am choosing is -
I have installed the filebeat on linux server where my application logs are getting generated  - >  parsing them via logstash and then - > sending them to elasticsearch

Questions I have are -
The linux server having application logs generates and stored logs in directories dynamically based on what day/month/time of the day its running for example my directory structure for logs on 06/10/2022 at 11:45 am will look like -

-/var/log/2022/06/10/11/abc.txt

I want my filebeat input path for logs in filebeat.yml to take paths dynamically so that I do not have to keep changing the paths and restarting the filebeat service so I tried to use something like - /var/log/2022/*/*/*/*.txt

But when I specify file path with wildcards like /var/log/2022/*/*/*/*.txt I get no logs shipped and the filebeat service runs fine but harvester always shows 0 files and no logs gets shipped however when I changes that to specifically point to any folder without using wildcard like -/var/log/2022/06/10/11/abc.txt the logs get shipped and I can see them in elasticsearch. So, I want to know what I should do in order to make this dynamic path work and the filebeat version I am using is  7.17.0.
Please let me know if you guys have any ideas.

*(Note: - There are 12 folders inside 2022 for months like - 01, 02, 03 etc ..
Inside those folders for months there are sub folders to support dates depending on how many days in the months like - 01, 02...29,30 ...etc
Inside those there are 23 subfolders for hours of the day like - 00,01,02...23 )*

2. Another question I have is whenever I get the logs to get shipped I see latency like I ideally want logs to immediately appear in Elasticsearch as soon as they appear in linux server where the application is running and generating the logs but I always see a latency like logs appears in elasticsearch at least with a delay of 5-15 mins so how can I make it appear as soon as they show up like real time ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a double asterisk? https://github.com/elastic/beats/pull/3980 implemented a change (FileBeat 6.0, so it should work in 7.x) to expand ** up to sixteen levels.

```
  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /path/to/logs/**/myfiles.log
```

Comment: Hey, can you provide me pattern for my use case because I tried - 
/var/log/2022/**/**/**/*.txt but this does not work either for me